# Justifying Calculations on $f(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\theta e^{-in \theta} d \theta$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

In Stein's Fourier Analysis i'm having trouble Justifying the following calculations for the Fourier Coefficients in $(1.)$

$(1.)$

Let $f(\theta) = \theta$ for $ -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$ in the case when $n \neq 0$:

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\theta e^{-in \theta} d \theta = \frac{1}{2 \pi}[-\frac{\theta}{in}e^{-in \theta}]_{-\pi}^{\pi} + \frac{1}{2 \pi in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-in\theta}d \theta = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in} $$

Then the Fourier Series of $f$ is given by:

$$ f(n) = \sum_{n \neq 0}  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}$$

Comment: This is integration by parts.  What are you having trouble justifying in it exactly?

Comment: I'm having trouble justifying the following operation: $\frac{1}{2 \pi}[-\frac{\theta}{in}e^{in \theta}]_{-\pi}^{\pi} + \frac{1}{2 \pi in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{in\theta}d \theta = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}$ specifcally where $\frac{\theta}{in}e^{in\theta}$ and $\frac{1}{2 \pi in}$ come from. In general i'm having trouble trying verify the calculation in the case when $n \neq 0$

Comment: Set $u = \theta$ and $dv = e^{-in\theta}$ and use the integration by parts formula.  Do you know how to integrate by parts?

Comment: Yes it should just follow straight for the definition I was initially asking because when I tried calculating the integral I could not get: $\frac{1}{2 \pi}[-\frac{\theta}{in}e^{in \theta}]_{-\pi}^{\pi} + \frac{1}{2 \pi in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{in\theta}d \theta = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}$ I don't understand why they added. Sorry if my post is skimpy on the work.

Comment: You have a typo in that line: you've got $e^{in\theta}$ both times and you should have $e^{-in\theta}$.  Does that help?  As for the adding: you get a - sign coming out of the integration of $e^{-in\theta}$ that combines with the - sign from the integration by parts formula to yield the + sign

Comment: I addressed the typo i'm having trouble understanding how calculations were done in the case $n \neq 0$, I understand how IBP was applied in the case of $n = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi}[-\frac{\theta}{in}e^{-in \theta}]_{-\pi}^{\pi} + \frac{1}{2 \pi in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-in\theta}d \theta$$
 $$=-\frac{1}{2 \pi}[\frac{\pi}{in}e^{-in \pi}-\frac{-\pi}{in}e^{+in \pi}] + \frac{1}{2 \pi in}\cdot \left[   \frac{e^{-in\theta}}{{-in}}\right] ^{\pi}_{-\pi} $$
$$=-\frac{1}{2 \pi}[\frac{\pi}{in}e^{-in \pi}-\frac{-\pi}{in}e^{+in \pi}] + \frac{1}{2 \pi in}\cdot \left[   \frac{e^{-in\pi}}{{-in}}-\frac{e^{+in\pi}}{{-in}}\right] $$
Since
$$ e^{n\pi i}= e^{-n\pi i}=(-1)^n$$
The second term cancels and the first term becomes:
$$-\frac{(-1)^n}{in}= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}$$

Comment: where did the $in$ come from that's the last thing I don't understand

Comment: $\int e^{ax} dx= \frac{e^{ax}}{a}+c$ Now let $a =-in$

Comment: Finally just to make sure$-\frac{1}{2 \pi}[\frac{\pi}{in}e^{-in \pi}-\frac{-\pi}{in}e^{+in \pi}] + \frac{1}{2 \pi in}\cdot \left[   \frac{e^{-in\theta}}{{-in}}\right] ^{\pi}_{-\pi}$, the RHS side of that operation is just an application of IBP twice correct ?